# iPad iOS 6.1 UIPopover ImagePicker crashes when pressing the bar button twice

Tags: ipad, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have created a popover for the `image picker` on the iPad. This function works. But if you press the `UIBarButton` twice the application crashes.

```
@property (retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController1;


-(IBAction)photos:(id)sender {

    test = false;

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    self.popoverController1 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

    _popoverController1.delegate = self;

    [_popoverController1 setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024, 500)];
    [self.popoverController1 presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What is error from the crash?

Comment: The proper thing to do is check to see if the popover is already displayed when the button is tapped. If so, dismiss the current popover. If not, display the popover.

Comment: This is the error:  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'

That is a great suggestion. Thank you! :D How would I check for that?

Comment: See if your `self.popoverController1` property is set or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to check whether popover is visible or not. If your have its object created then dismiss it and again create popover

```
if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [popoverController setDelegate:nil];
    [popoverController release]; // Use release only if , it is without ARC
}
else
{
    // Create popover and assign its properties.
}
```

This will definitely solve your issues in all the iOS versions. :) Have a happy coding.!!